# What permissions do I need to use Google Cloud Machine Learning from a GCE VM?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

What permissions do I need to access Google Cloud Machine Learning from a GCE VM?

I followed the instructions and ran the check environment script but got an error about insufficient authentication scopes

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ml/scripts/check_environment.py | python
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3802  100  3802    0     0  31451      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 31683
Your active configuration is: [default]

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   138    0   138    0     0    973      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   978
ERROR: Unable to list Cloud ML models: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I'm running on a GCE VM which uses the default compute service account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Cloud Machine Learning API you need

1. Editor permissions for the project in order to submit jobs, create models, etc...
2. GCS read/write permissions.

This means if you are running a GCE VM and using a service account

1. The service account should be an editor for the project you are using with GCE.

   - This will be true if you are using the default compute engine account.
2. The VM must be created with GCS read/write scopes.